# Find the minimum time when workers can handle tasks simultaneously but have to wait to start

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

I encountered a problem similar to [leetcode 1732](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-minimum-time-to-finish-all-jobs/description/), which I can find a solution of. The problem goes like this

You are given an integer array `jobs`, where `jobs[i]` is the amount of time it takes to complete the `i`th job.

There are `k` workers that you can assign jobs to. Each worker can handle 4 tasks simultaneously. For example, when a worker is allocated with tasks `[1,2,3,4]`, they will take 4 units of time to finish. However, each worker has to wait a few units of time before they can start working. Suppose `wait` is a list of `k` numbers, each number being the amount of wait time. For example, if `k[1] = 3`, worker 1 has to wait 3 units of time before they start. If `k = 1` is assigned `[1,2,3,4]`, then it will take 4+3 = 7 for the worker to finish.

Find the minimum work time for the workers to finish all the jobs. As an example, suppose `jobs = [3,3,4,2,9,8,5,6]` and `k = 2`, and `wait = [9,11]`. We can allocate `[3,4,8,9]` to worker 1 and `[5,3,6,2]` to worker 2. Then the time required to finish all jobs would be 18.

As another example, there is only one worker and their wait time is 3. There are 1 task with duration 2 and 4 tasks with duration 1. Workers don't need to wait to re-start after having already worked on a set of tasks. Therefore, it will take a total of 6 regardless of how you arrange the tasks.

Also, it's impossible to have multiple workers working on the same task.

I'm totally clueless on this one and I don't know how to map it to leetcode 1732 (should I?). Can I please get some help?

Comment: Are there enough workers for all tasks, or may workers have to be reused? Also, would there be any reason _not_ to group the 4 longest-running tasks together, then the next 4, etc.?

Comment: Workers can be re-used. Do you minimize work time by grouping the 4 longest tasks together?

Comment: If work-time is determined by the the longest of the four tasks, then yes, I think so. Still have to figure out which task-group to assign to which worker (with which wait-time), esp. whether to use the shortest wait-time for the longest task (least overall time), or for the shortest tasks (least repeated wait-time if the worker is re-used).

Comment: Say a worker is assigned 4 tasks. They wait, and then begin their tasks. Once they finish the first of these, can they immediately start working on a new task, or do they need to wait first, or do they need to finish the other 3 before they start waiting or working on new tasks?

Comment: Could you give an example where a worker has to pick up additional tasks? That will clear up some ambiguities.

Comment: Is this [greedy number-partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_number_partitioning)?

Comment: What would happen in this case: one worker with wait-time 3, 1 task with duration 2, 4 tasks with duration 1. Would it be "wait 3, do (2,1,1,1) in parallel, wait 3, do (1)" for a total time of 9, or "wait 3, do (2,1,1,1) in parallel, then do (1)", for a time of 6, or "wait 3, do (2,1,1,1) in parallel, start (1) as soon as the first 1-task is finished", for a time of 5?

Comment: @Dave They can immediately start.

Comment: @tobias_k Wait 3, do (2,1,1,1) and (1) or do (1,1,1,1) and (2) so the total time is 6 regardless. Don't need to wait again.

Answer (score 0):

Heuristic, not optimal solution, to this NP-hard Multiway Number Partitioning problem:

Assumptions:

- waiting only applies once per worker, not once per job
- whenever a worker finishes a job, they can immediately replace it with a new job.
- multiple workers can't tackle the same job simultaneously to good effect.

Associate each worker with start_times, an array of four integers all initialized to that workers' wait time.

Put all workers in a min heap by min(start_times)

Repeatedly:

- Pop the top worker
- The min(start_times) will be repeated k times, 1 <= k <= 4.
- Take the k longest remaining jobs, increment the k mins start times (arbitrarily) by the length of these k jobs, and but the worker back in the heap.

As you do the above, keep track of the max value ever to appear in a worker's start_times. When we're done, this will be the time it takes to complete the last job.

Running time: Say there are n jobs and m workers. Each time we pop a worker we determine the completion time of at least 1 job. Updating the heap takes log m effort each time, so this is O(n log m)

--- update ---

Your problem is essentially [Multiway Number Partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning), which is NP-hard. The difference is your wait times, but I don't think that affects the approaches or complexity analysis. What I gave is the [(sorted) Greedy Number Partitioning heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_number_partitioning).

Comment: If waiting is once per job rather than worker, then you can use this approach but in the increment step, increment by the length of the job(s) + wait time, to represent the time before the worker can start working again.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a formal name for this class of algorithms?

Comment: @user1691278 We're greedily allocating the longest remaining task to the worker who's first free to work on it, so 'greedy.'

Comment: @user1691278 You've confirmed my first two assumptions. Can you confirm the third as well -- that having multiple workers working on the same task isn't an option or doesn't help?

Comment: I just confirmed it.

Comment: I think this fails for `wait=[0,2], jobs=[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,10,10,10,10]`.  All jobs can be done in 12, but greedy approach returns 14

Comment: @MattTimmermans Right as usual. Just realized this is the NP-hard multiway number partitioning problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning).

Comment: @Dave what do you mean by "The min(start_times) will be repeated k times, 1 <= k <= 4."? I have four start times. Shouldn't you repeat max(start_times)? Because it will take 4 to finish `[1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: @user1691278 I was assuming that the worker doing [1,2,3,4] would have capacity to start a new job after they finished the first of their 4 jobs, not the last. That's what my second assumption was about. Is that wrong -- do workers need to finish all four jobs before they can start any new ones?

Comment: @Dave Yes, you're right. I missed your point.